# Adding two types of object to mutableListOf<MyInterface>()

Tags: list, kotlin, mutable

```
interface ListItem {
    val style: ItemStyle
    val identifier: ListItemIdentifier? 
}

 val mutableList = mutableListOf<ListItem>()
```

I have a list that I map to objects and group:

```
dataList.groupBy { it.type }.forEach { (type, itemList) ->

              val type = TypeHeader(name = type.name )

              val items = itemList.map {  item ->
                    Item(
                        title = item.title,
                        subtitle = item.subtitle
                    )
                }
        mutableList.addAll(listOf(type , items ))
    }
```

I need to add that objects to my `mutableList` but when I try

```
mutableList.addAll(listOf(type , items ))
```

there is a error

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
Collection<ListItem>
Found:
List<Any>
```

when I try cast listOf as ListItem app crashes

Comment: Are you sure you provided the full error message? `List` should be fine when required a `Collection`, I guess the problem is with type parameters (enclosed with `<` and `>`), but you didn't provide them. What are `category` and `archiveItems`?

Comment: My bad. I updated my question.

Comment: Ok, do you maybe try to create a list like e.g.: `[header, item, item, header, item]`, etc.? In that case you really need to do it like this: `mutableList.add(type); mutableList.addAll(items);`.

Comment: In `mutableList.addAll(...)` you are giving `Any` argument. You need to declare which type of data you are giving as an argument. Use `ArrayList<ListItem>(...)` where `...` are aguments for your `ListItem` constructor.

Comment: Does both `Item` and `TypeHeader` implement `ListItem`? If not, why are you trying to add them both to a list of `ListItem`s?

Comment: @broot yes I try something like you wrote. I did it and it works. Thanks

Comment: One more question. How Can I sort "type" list?

Comment: If you mean that after grouping you would need to sort by `type`, then replace your `groupBy` with: `groupByTo(sortedMapOf()) { it.type }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some discussion in comments we got to the solution.

The problem is in this `listOf()` line. You try to mix `type`, which is a single item and `items` which is a list of items. `listOf()` does not magically flatten this to e.g.: `[header, item, item, item]`. It will create something like this instead: `[header, [item, item, item]]`. This is inferred to the list of `Any` objects, because some items are single objects and some are lists.

You can flatten `header` and `items` to a single list with:

```kotlin
listOf(header) + items
```

But in this case it is better to just add to `mutableList` twice:

```kotlin
mutableList.add(type)
mutableList.addAll(items)
```